Are there terminologies for "one-to-one" but not "onto" functions, and "onto" but not "one-to-one" functions?
One-to-one (injective) functions are not necessarily not onto (not surjective).
Similarly, onto functions are not necessarily not one-to-one.
So, a function can be one-to-one and onto (bijective).
$f(x)=e^x$ is one-to-one but not onto $\big($it will be onto for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ not $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$\big)$
$f(x)=x^2$ is onto but not one-to-one for $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,\infty)$.

So is there a short common terminology for "one-to-one but not onto", or "onto but not one-to-one" ?

Thanks!

as far as I know, no specific word for this. The shortest way to say this is : let $f$ be a function from $A$ to $B$ injective and not surjective ...

Can "surjective non-injective" & "injective non-surjective" work ?

You need to clarify whether by "not onto" you mean 1) we definitely know that it is not onto, or 2) we have no knowledge as to whether or not it is onto (as DavidRenfro commented on an answer). Sadly, in neither situation is there a common term that is any shorter than just describing both properties.

Injective = one-to-one.  Surjective = onto.  Bijective = both one-to-one and onto.  If you want to specify one property but not the other use either injective or surjective.

But, injective doesn’t mean “one-to-one but not onto.”

To add to what @littleO said in a comment, "specify one property but not the other" most likely means "specify one property holds and do not specify the other property holds" (i.e. the scope of "specify" extends past "but"). It probably does NOT mean "specify one property holds and specify the other property does not hold". The OP wants the latter and your answer gives the former.

Totally disagree.
